# Estimated inverse function is not continous

Tags: r, inverse

I estimated the cdf of my density in an interval of length 0.03 with 10k points. Even though my cdf is pretty smooth, my inverse of the cdf isn't smooth at all. Here the interval of length 1 is also evaluated with 10k points.

See: [Estimated CDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk0DY.png) & [Estimated Inverse CDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQqFM.png)

For the Inverse CDF I use:

`x = seq(from = 0, to = 1, length = 10000)
F_hat_inv_given_x = function(y){
  uniroot(function(x){
    F_hat_given_x(x)-y
  },interval=c(0.065, 0.095))$root
}
F_hat_inv_given_x = Vectorize(F_hat_inv_given_x)`

with F_hat_given_x defined as:

`F_hat_given_x = function(y) {
  integrate(f = f_hat_given_x, min(y_data), y)$value
}
F_hat_given_x <- Vectorize(F_hat_given_x)`

where f_hat_given_x is my density:

`f_hat_given_x = function(y){
  tapply(y, x = x_sample, FUN = f_hat, INDEX = 1:length(y))
}`

which is a conditional density f(y | X = x) for a given sample X = x_sample:

`f_hat = function(x, y){
  (sum(K(abs(x-x_data)/H_n) * (K(abs(y-y_data)/h_n)))) / (h_n * sum(K(abs(x-x_data)/H_n)))
}`

with K being the gaussian kernel, h_n, H_n are bandwidths computed via npcdensbw and x_data and y_data are my given data on which I evaluate the conditional density f_hat(x,y)

Any idea why the inverse function isn't monotone increasing like the inverse should? What is causing the inaccuracity?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `F_hat_given_x` is not defined in your code.

Comment: Edited my post and added the code for the cde, the density function and the estimator which is the base for the density estimation.